# Best practice for maintaining a php.ini file

Tags: php

I'd like to increase [Matomo's](https://matomo.org/) PHP memory limit, which as I understand needs to be done in a `php.ini` file. However, my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system has many of them: one for each version of PHP.

What's the best practice for maintaining one here?

Comment: the good old editor and a clean installation. you should know what php version is installed and what csn be removed safely

Comment: php -i will list which ini files it has loaded.